# Remove debug mode throughout the flutter using code once

Tags: flutter, dart

1.How to remove debug mode from all the widgets without writing debugShowCheckedMode:false for each page..
2.I want to write debugShowCheckedmode:false only once... How can I do this? 3.Is it possible to disable debug mode throughout the app by writing only a single line of code?

Comment: [`debugShowCheckedModeBanner`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/debugShowCheckedModeBanner.html) is a property of a `MaterialApp`, not of each widget.  If you want to disable the debug mode *banner*, you need to do it only in one place.  If you don't want debug mode itself, then build your application in release mode.

Comment: I don't know what is release mode .Can you please explain about it? or provide any link to tutorials? Thank you...

Comment: Release mode means you have to build your application using " Flutter build apk " command. but i suggest you to don't do that. First create your app and always run in debug mode.

Comment: You should use debug mode when you're developing and testing your application.  You should use release mode when you're ready to ship it to customers.  See: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes

Comment: Thank you very much for this information..I am a beginner to flutter..even small bit of knowledge is worthy  for me

Comment: how many MaterialApp theme use in your project?

Answer (score 2):

Just simply add this snippet into your main Material App widget file.

```
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
```

Comment: If you want to need example of that code then you can refer this link. http://techandroidhub.com/remove-debug-banner-in-the-flutter-app/